# Nested HTML table binding in mvc3

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3

I need to bind html table from controller . its look like

```
<table>
<tr>
<td>Mvc Books</td>
<td>
<table>
<tr><td>Book1</td></tr>
<tr><td>Book1</td></tr>
<tr><td>Book1</td></tr>
</table>
</td>
<td>Mvc Books</td>
<td>
<table>
<tr><td>Book1</td></tr>
<tr><td>Book1</td></tr>
<tr><td>Book1</td></tr>
</table>
</td>
<tr>
</table>
```

how to bind using MVC model and controller.

Answer (score 1):

This is basis:

Model:

```
public class book
{
public string bookname {get; set;}
....
}
```

Controller:

```
public ActionResult GetBooks()
{
  List<book> books = db.books.ToList()
  return View(books)
}
```

View:

```
@model IEnumerable<yourApp.Models.book>

<table>
@foreach(var book in Model)
{
<tr>
<td>@book.bookname</td>
</tr>
}
</table>
```

EDITED:

```
<table>
<tr>
<td>Mvc Books</td>
<td>
<table>
    @foreach(var book in Model)
    {
    <tr>
    <td>@book.bookname</td>
    </tr>
    }
    </table>
</td>
</tr>
</table>
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply.I need to show the list of Books in next Td.Its almost like Nested table.we can do this in ASP.Net grid view.

Comment: Do you have solution?

Comment: the code you given for only one book.need to bind number of books,each book will have multiple sub books.I need to bind the 'book name' from controller(using list).

Comment: @vijay52 I can't write code instead of you, I just give you an idea how to do it. What you asked works absolutly the same. And there are a lot of ways to do it. Look at any tutorial to work with ViewModels and complex models.